# passing argument to WordCram code

Tags: java, class, static, processing

I have the following question: I am trying to execute the usConstitution wordcram example (code follows) and if provided as is the code executes in eclipse, the applet starts and the word cloud is created. (code follows)

```
import processing.core.*; 
//import processing.xml.*; 

import wordcram.*; 
import wordcram.text.*; 

import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.Dimension; 
import java.awt.Frame; 
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent; 
import java.awt.Image; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.text.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.zip.*; 
import java.util.regex.*; 

public class usConstitution extends PApplet {

/*
US Constitution text from http://www.usconstitution.net/const.txt
Liberation Serif font from RedHat: https://www.redhat.com/promo/fonts/
*/

WordCram wordCram;

public void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(255);
  colorMode(HSB);

  initWordCram();
}

public void initWordCram() {
  wordCram = new WordCram(this)
      .fromTextFile("http://www.usconstitution.net/const.txt")
      .withFont(createFont("https://www.redhat.com/promo/fonts/", 1))
      .sizedByWeight(10, 90)
      .withColors(color(0, 250, 200), color(30), color(170, 230, 200));
}

public void draw() {
  if (wordCram.hasMore()) {
    wordCram.drawNext();
  }
}

public void mouseClicked() {
  background(255);
  initWordCram();
}

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] { "--bgcolor=#ECE9D8", "usConstitution" });
    }
}
```

My problem is the following:

I want to pass through main (which is the only static class) an argument so as to call the usConstitution.class from another class providing whichever valid filename I want in order to produce its word cloud. So how do I do that? I tried calling usConstitution.main providing some args but when I try to simply print the string I just passed to main (just to check if it is passed) I get nothing on the screen. So the question is How can I pass an argument to this code to customize .fromTextFile inside initWordCram ?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from: https://wordcram.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/get-acquainted-with-wordcram/ :

Daniel Bernier says:
June 11, 2013 at 1:13 am

You can’t pass command-line args directly to WordCram, because it has no executable.

But you can make an executable wrapper (base it on the IDE examples that come with WordCram), and it can read command-line args & pass them to WordCram as needed.

FYI, it’ll still pop up an Applet somewhere – AFAIK, you can’t really run Processing “headless.” But that’s usually only a concern if you’re trying to run on a server.